# AKS Assign a DNS name to private ClusterIP address

Tags: azure, kubernetes, microservices, azure-aks

I don't know how to implement this problem:
I have this private AKS cluster with 4 microservices (.net5) and a frontend. These 4 microservices talk to each other via HTTP requests using their public IP addresses (not good because I want them to have only a private endpoint, like *microservicename.api.my-namespace.svc.cluster-domain.example*).
Frontend (that has a public DNS and IP) should then be able to request a main API in that private endpoint.
I need to implement a solution to this, and also I feel like that communicating between microservices via HTTP requests on a certain endpoint is not a good design pattern, so I wanted some suggestions on this aspect also.
Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

•   You can use the Azure Private Link Service in this case to establish communication between the private AKS cluster and the frontend through the private endpoint that will be exposed in the subnet of the private AKS cluster.

•   The Private Link service is supported on Standard Azure Load Balancer only. Basic Azure Load Balancer isn't supported. To use a custom DNS server, add the Azure DNS IP 168.63.129.16 as the upstream DNS server in the custom DNS server.

•   You can create a private AKS cluster consisting of the four microservices using the below command with a private DNS zone or a custom private DNS zone: -

‘az aks create -n  -g  --load-balancer-sku standard --enable-private-cluster --enable-managed-identity --assign-identity  --private-dns-zone [system|none]’ – with a private DNS zone (system for default value & none for public DNS zone)

‘az aks create -n  -g  --load-balancer-sku standard --enable-private-cluster --enable-managed-identity --assign-identity  --private-dns-zone  --fqdn-subdomain ’

[image: Private AKS with custom DNS]

•   If the Private DNS Zone is in a different subscription than the AKS cluster, you need to register Microsoft.ContainerServices in both the subscriptions. Additionally, you will need a user assigned identity or service principal with at least the private dns zone contributor and vnet contributor roles. "fqdn-subdomain" can be utilized with "CUSTOM_PRIVATE_DNS_ZONE_RESOURCE_ID" only to provide subdomain capabilities to privatelink..azmk8s.io

•   Next, you would need to use a VM that has access to the AKS cluster's Azure Virtual Network (VNet). There are several options for establishing network connectivity to the private cluster such as create a VM in the same Azure Virtual Network (VNet) as the AKS cluster or use a VM in a separate network and set up Virtual network peering. Thus, you can create a private link with a private endpoint for the four microservices in the private AKS cluster and provide connection to the frontend API.

Please refer the below link for more details: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/private-clusters